# Pandas Multi Level Groupby: Pass grouped value range to function

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with three columns: 'Company Name', 'Product', 'Spend'.

Now I want to do the following:
1) Groupby 'Company Name' and 'Product' to see the money spend per Company and Product.

```
grouped=df.groupby(['Company Name', 'Product'])
```

2) Iterate only over the 'Company Name' column of grouped and pass the values of 'Spends' as a list to a function.

I don't know how to do the second step!

The pandas documentation only explains how to iterate over both indexes, not how to do it only for the first one.
I also tried this:

```
grouped.reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
```

but it throws an error.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you only groupby `Company name` if you want to iterate over it?

Comment: I want to see how (un)equal a company's spent is distributed  in it's product portfolio. To be precise, I want to calculate the Gini-Coefficient for a companies product portfolio. That's why I need the groupby product as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will iterate over the values of `Spend` (as a list) that have been grouped by `Company Name` and `Product`, and pass the list to your function.

```
df.groupby(['Company Name', 'Product'])['Spend'].apply(lambda x: my_func(list(x)))
```

Based on your comment, if you want to iterate over `Company Name` and get `[50, 45]` and pass it to a function:

```
for name in df['Company Name'].unique():
    list_spend = df.groupby(['Company Name', 'Product']).sum()['Spend'][name].tolist()
    my_func(list_spend)
```

Comment: Thank you bakka, that almost works! The only problem is that this doesn't iterate over the grouped (=aggregated) Spends per Product. 

I have several rows for one Company-Product with different spends. E.g.:
Company A:
Product Y: 50
Product Z: 15
Product Z: 20

The function gives me [50, [15, 20]] instead of [50, 45].

Comment: `df.groupby(['Company Name', 'Product']).sum()['Spend'].apply(lambda x: my_func([x]))` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
spent_list = df[["Company Name","Spend"]].groupby("Company Name").sum()["Spend"].values
spent_list = list(spent_list)
```

Now you have `spent_list`, which stores how much each company spent in total for all products.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have the split per product for a company.